# React - Force Reload Of Component

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-async

In my component - I am calling out to a service class that performs an async call.
I pass a callback to the service and use that when the async call is complete.

Is it possible to force a reload of the component from this callback method?

Thanks
Damien

Comment: You can use `forceUpdate`. You can read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate